# Decoding H.264 file to YUV with deblocking filter

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion

When I'm decoding a H.264 file to YUV using ffmpeg, the deblocking filter flag is disabled. 
I ran the ffmpeg code in Linux using the command

```
./ffmpeg -f h264 -i input.h264 output.yuv
```

Can anyone tell me how to enable the deblocking filter flag in ffmpeg code?

Is there any option to enable the deblocking filter from command line while decoding the H.264 file in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other codecs, in h.264 deblocking is part of the encoding process and not the decoding process.